expo auth session and redirecting back to my app
I'm building the mobile version for a website, and using the identity server for authentication,
I'm using expo-auth-session for handling this but I'm facing a problem redirecting back to my app, is there something missing in my implementation
this is my login component

  const clientId = 'Android.Hybrid';
  const clientSecret = 'And@Passw0rd';
  const scopes = ['openid', 'profile', 'MotorInsurance', 'Identity', 'offline_access'];
  const codeChallengeMethod = 'S256';

  const extraParams = {};
  const redirectUri = 'com.eltizam.app://signin-oidc';
  const discovery = AuthSession.useAutoDiscovery('https://api-qc.eltizam.sa/identity');
  // Create and load an auth request,
  const [request, result, promptAsync] = AuthSession.useAuthRequest(
    {
      clientId,
      responseType: 'code',

      redirectUri,
      clientSecret,
      scopes,
    },
    discovery
  );


  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>

     

        <ButtonComponent
         
          handlePress={() => promptAsync()}       
        />
    </View>
  );
};

export default Logi

the redirect uri that's saved in the BE database is com.eltizam.app and com.eltizam.app://sign-oidc
the problem is after I sign in in the browser tab, expo redirect me back to the application with erro (unmatched route)
error
and this is my app.json file
app.json file
is there something in the configuration i'm missing ?
i'm expecting the browser tab to redirect me back to the application with the code to fetch the access token
